# TypeError: dataset must be a Dataset or a DatasetReference(GBQ)

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery

I am trying to list out Datasets within a project and tables within a dataset,but unable to understand the meaning of `TypeError: dataset must be a Dataset or a Dataset Reference`

**Code 1 : List datasets within a project**

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

GBQ_client = bigquery.Client(project= config.PROJECT_ID)
print  GBQ_client.list_datasets()
```

**Output:**

```
<google.api_core.page_iterator.HTTPIterator object at 0x000000000660ACF8>
```

**Code 2 : List tables within a dataset**

```
tables = GBQ_client.list_tables(dataset = config.Dataset_ID)
```

where config.Dataset_ID = 'projectId:xxxxxxx'

**Output:**

```
TypeError: dataset must be a Dataset or a DatasetReference
```

Answer (score 0):

To list all datasets within your project you were close, you just need to iterate over the `HTTPIterator` now:

```
datasets = list(GBQ_client.list_datasets())
```

Now to iterate over tables you probably have several ways to do so. If you have a specific *datasetId* such as "dataset123" then one way you could do is:

```
dataset = [dataset for dataset in client.list_datasets() if dataset.dataset_id == 'dataset123'][0] # be careful, if empty this will break
tables = list(client.list_tables(dataset=dataset.reference))
```

And tables will be a list with items associated to each table you have in "dataset123".

If you know upfront the name of the table you can retrieve it directly:

```
table = dataset.table('your table name')
```

Notice that [`list_tables`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L404) method expects either an object from `bigquery.dataset.Dataset` or `bigquery.dataset.DatasetReference` to work; as it seems, you used a string in `config.dataset` so it won't be accepted as input (notice I used `dataset.reference` as input for this method).

Comment: hey many for your support, I have already used list method to list out the datasets but its is showing the empty set but I have 20+ datasets at the console under that project. what I am missing?

Comment: hmm...it should have worked. I wonder what is the value of `project_id` in your service account json? is it the same as the one you're listing datasets on?